# How to define type for replacement function in replace method in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to define types for replace method in TypeScript but I am getting this error:

> No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following
> error.
> Argument of type '(match: string, value: string) => string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(substring: string,
> ...args: any[]) => string'.
> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2769)

Here is my code:

```
const newStr = str.replace(myRegExp, (match: string, value: string) => {
        if (!value) return match;
    }),
);
```

How can I do this in typescript?

Comment: TypeScript shows you a logical problem in your code. Your JavaScript code would also be wrong. What is the expected behavior, if the `if` condition is wrong? The callback function should return a string on all possible paths.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To convert this JavaScript code to TypeScript, you can simply add type annotations for the function parameters and the return type. Here's an example:

```
const newStr: string = str.replace(myRegExp, (match: string, value: string): string => {
    if (!value) return match;
});
```

In this example, the match and value parameters are annotated as string, and the return type of the function is also annotated as string.

Comment: This suppresses the error message, but it doesn't solve the problem. The callback function returns `undefined`, if `value` is truthy. The typing is wrong. You should either change the return type or return a string on all possible paths.